# update image in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and i want to update image in codeigniter.But the problem is that when i call update method then image is doesnot store in database.The console window show this error.  (Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form.  The file will not be sent.) Help me how can i solve it.
Here is my code view file:

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  action="<?php echo site_url('User/update_image')?>" role="form" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-control">
  <p><input hidden type="text" name="companyid" value="<?php echo $row->pro_id; ?>" /></p>
<div class="profile-userpic">     
<img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="<?php echo base_url().'image/'.$row->professional_image; ?>" />
</div>
<br>    

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="file" name="userfile"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input type="submit" class="cen" name="submit" value="upload" />
</div>
</div>

</form>
```

Here is code of my  controller where i wrote update method.

```
public function update_image()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './image';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                $this->upload->do_upload();
                $dataa = array('upload_data'=>  $this->upload->data());

                $professional_info = array(
                'professional_image'=>  $dataa['upload_data']['file_name']);

                $this->UserModel->update_professional_image($professional_info);
                redirect('Professional/professional_profile_personal_info');
        }
```

Here is code of my model:

```
public function update_professional_image($data)
        {
            $this->db->where('fk_user_id' , $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
            return $this->db->update('professional',$data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems u have enctype=multipart/form-control instead of enctype=multipart/form-data. For file uploads, enctype=multipart/form-data is used.

Switch to the same, and it should start working.

Comment: For resizing image during insert what we will try

Comment: Please write the method how i resize the image during inserting or during updating

Comment: You can refer to the following url [codeigniter image_lib link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html). You can get better idea as how to resize the image with codeigniter image_lib with ease.

Comment: Please little abit help how i add this resize code into my above code

Comment: You may check the code in [my gist](https://gist.github.com/blakdronzer/a5f25172549d95dd82f5ba34d68b483e).  I have created a sample piece of code from your method / functionality.

Comment: Thank you much Blakdronzer for this help.I try your code but the image is not resized.I will try again.Thans for this help

Answer (score 0):

```
first of all change your enctype="multipart/form-control" to enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Now use this configuration. hope it will help you

```
$path = realpath(APPPATH. './image');
$config['upload_path'] = $path;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size']     = '100';
$config['max_width'] = '1024';
$config['max_height'] = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) 
{
    $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
}
else
{
     $filename = $this->upload->data();
     $professional_info['userfile'] = $filename['file_name'];
     $this->UserModel->update_professional_image($professional_info);
     redirect('Professional/professional_profile_personal_info');
}
```